# article - absolute value

Tags: articles, mathematics

Is the article before the absolute value? I know that there is always an article in phrases like the absolute value of sth but I saw the sentence below without any article. Is it right? Thank you

> *A* increases in (the) absolute value as d increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

"Absolute value" here is a **property** of *A*. Just as you might say "*A* increases in redness as *d* increases", meaning A becomes redder, you can apply that sentence structure to any property.

Using *the* for "absolute value" is right when you are talking about a **particular instance** of that property:

> The absolute value of *A* is 7.
> The redness of this apple is greater than that one. (Not particularly idiomatic, but valid.)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Where can I find this rule about ptoperties in literature or in a webpage, please?